Component groups of stabilizers for linear representations
Let $G$ be a connected simple reductive group over $\mathbb C$. Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional complex representation of $G$.
Given a vector $v \in V$, it is natural to consider its stabilizer group $G_v=\{ g \in G | gv=v\} \leq G$. It turns out that $G_v$ could be disconnected. Let $A_v=\pi_0(G_v)$ be the finite component group of $G_v$.
Examples:

Consider the irreducible representation of $G=\mathrm {SL}_2$ on $V=\mathrm{Sym^2} \mathbb C^2$ as the space of cubic forms $f \in \mathbb C[x,y]$. Then the stabilizer of $f=xy(x-y)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/3$.

Consider the adjoint representation and a nilpotent element $v \in \mathrm{Lie} G$. By classification, $A_v$ is a direct sum of $\mathbb Z / 2$ when $G$ is classical, but $A_v=S_n, n \leq 5$ (symmetric group) may happen when $G$ is exceptional.


Observations:

When $V=V_1 \oplus V_2$, then for $v=(v_1, v_2)$ we have $G_v=G_{v_1} \cap G_{v_2}$, but the relation between component groups seem mysterious.

For any affine $G$-variety $X$, there exists a linear representation $\rho: G \to \mathrm{GL}(V)$ and an $G$-equivariant embedding $\iota: X \to V$. In particular, $G_x=G_{\iota(x)}$ for $x \in X$. In particular, given a subgroup $H \leq G$ such that $G/H$ is quasi-affine (e.g. when $H$ is reductive), $H$ will arise as $G_v$ for some $v$. So, for general $V$, the question may be too random.


Here are my questions:

Given $G$, let $V$ vary, which component group $A_v$ may occur?
When $G$ is classical and $V$ is irreducible or a direct sum of two irreducible representations, is $A_v$ abelian?
Given $V$, for a generic vector $v \in V$, is $A_v$ abelian?
Given $V$, could we classify all $A_v$?
Are there good conditions on $V$ to make that $A_v$ is trivial for generic $v$ (or for any $v$)?


I might be forgetting something, but $G/H$ quasi-affine allows for $H$ to be disconnected, so doesn't your second point imply that ANY disconnected subgroup with reductive identity component can arise for some $V$? Take $S_k\times \mathrm{Sp}{2n-2k}$ in $\mathrm{Sp}{2n}$. Does that statement not apply to this?

@SpencerLeslie You are right. I have some examples in mind e.g. direct sum of two irreducible representations. In general, if we do not fix $G$, any component group will occur. If we fix $G$, then we are classifying component groups of subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that $G/H$ is quasi-affine.
